# Insert forward slash between double quotes using sed

Tags: sed, escaping

This is my string in a file:

```
url = "http://some.com";
```

I'd like to change it to:

```
url = "http://someother.com";
```

using:

```
sed -i 's/url = ".*"/url = "http://someother.com"/g' index.html
```

but I'm getting this error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'
```

If I remove the two forward slashes from the string I'm inserting it works fine. How can I escape these?

Comment: `sed -i 's/url = ".*"/url = "http:\/\/someother.com"/g' index.html`

Comment: `sed -i 's|url = ".*"|url = "http://someother.com"|g' index.html`